# How to read 2 comma separated string in single loop - XSLT

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, ibm-datapower, exslt

I have below two variables which have multiple commas separated string values in  different XSLT variable

```
Variable_01 : 88888,777777
Variable_02 : abc,xyz
```

Now I am looking for below output

```
[{"Group":"88888", "Name":"abc"},{"Group":"777777", "Name":"xyz"}]
```

Could you please help me what is correct XSLT code for the above output.

Comment: How are the variables being set, by the way? Do they just contain static strings, or values passed in as parameters? Or are they set by the XSLT using values from the input XML? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way you could look at it:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:variable name="Variable_01">88888,777777</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="Variable_02">abc,xyz</xsl:variable>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:text>[</xsl:text>
    <xsl:for-each select="tokenize($Variable_01, ',')">
        <xsl:variable name="i" select="position()"/>
        <xsl:text>{"Group":"</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
        <xsl:text>", "Name":"</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="tokenize($Variable_02, ',')[$i]" />
        <xsl:text>"}</xsl:text>
        <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:text>]</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
[{"Group":"88888", "Name":"abc"},{"Group":"777777", "Name":"xyz"}]
```

---

**Demo**: http://xsltransform.hikmatu.com/jyH9rLV

Comment: Thank you Michael for quick response

my problem still not fixed, now i am getting error message tokenize function not recognize

Comment: @MayurGaikwad Why did you tag your question as XSLT 2.0, when your processor does not support it? -- If you're using IBM DataPower, then you should be able to use the EXSLT `str:tokenize()` extension function instead.

Comment: apologize Michael for this, Just now i correct this tag. If you have idea, could you please help me

Comment: @MayurGaikwad I already did. Read the help for the function, either on the EXSLT site or in the DataPower manual.

Comment: Thank you Michael :) I issue has been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

In XSLT 3 with higher-order function `for-each-pair` and JSON map and array support this would be as easy as

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/math"
    xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map"
    xmlns:array="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/array"
    xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

    <xsl:output method="json" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:param name="Variable_01" as="xs:string">88888,777777</xsl:param>
    <xsl:param name="Variable_02" as="xs:string">abc,xyz</xsl:param>

    <xsl:template match="/" name="xsl:initial-template">
        <xsl:sequence 
         select="array { 
                   for-each-pair(
                     tokenize($Variable_01, ','),
                     tokenize($Variable_02, ','),
                     function($a, $b) { map { 'Group' : $a, 'Name' : $b } }
                   )
                 }"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In XSLT 3 without higher-order function support for `for-each-pair` you could implement your own function along the lines of the defintion:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/math"
    xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map"
    xmlns:array="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/array"
    xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

    <xsl:output method="json" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:function name="mf:object-for-each-pair" as="map(xs:string, xs:string)*">
      <xsl:param name="seq1"/>
      <xsl:param name="seq2"/>
      <xsl:param name="action"/>
      <xsl:if test="exists($seq1) and exists($seq2)">
        <xsl:sequence select="map { 'Group' : head($seq1), 'Name' : head($seq2) }"/>
        <xsl:sequence select="mf:object-for-each-pair(tail($seq1), tail($seq2))"/>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:function>

    <xsl:param name="Variable_01" as="xs:string">88888,777777</xsl:param>
    <xsl:param name="Variable_02" as="xs:string">abc,xyz</xsl:param>

    <xsl:template match="/" name="xsl:initial-template">
        <xsl:sequence select="array { mf:object-for-each-pair(tokenize($Variable_01, ','), tokenize($Variable_02, ',')) }"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6qVRKxk

Finally in XSLT 2 without JSON array and map support you could use the same approach to create text output instead:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:output method="text"/>

    <xsl:function name="mf:object-for-each-pair" as="xs:string*">
      <xsl:param name="seq1"/>
      <xsl:param name="seq2"/>
      <xsl:if test="exists($seq1) and exists($seq2)">
        <xsl:sequence select="concat('{ &quot;Group&quot; : &quot;', $seq1[1], '&quot;, &quot;Name&quot; : &quot;', $seq2[1], '&quot; }')"/>
        <xsl:sequence select="mf:object-for-each-pair(subsequence($seq1, 2), subsequence($seq2, 2))"/>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:function>

    <xsl:param name="Variable_01" as="xs:string">88888,777777</xsl:param>
    <xsl:param name="Variable_02" as="xs:string">abc,xyz</xsl:param>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:text>[ </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="mf:object-for-each-pair(tokenize($Variable_01, ','), tokenize($Variable_02, ','))" separator=", "/>
        <xsl:text> ]</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

http://xsltransform.hikmatu.com/nc4NzPX

Comment: AFAIK, `head()` and `tail()` are new in XSLT 3.0.

Comment: @michael.hor257k, yes, you are right, I overlooked that in my attempt to morph the XSLT 3 code into XSLT 2, also need to remove the `name="xsl:initial-template"`.

Comment: Thank you Martin for quick response

my problem still not fixed, now i am getting error message tokenize function not recognize

Answer (score 0):

This is somewhat crude. But it gets the job done.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

    <xsl:variable name="Variable_01">88888,777777</xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="Variable_02">abc,xyz</xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:text>[</xsl:text>
        <xsl:call-template name="tokenizeString">
            <!-- store anything left in another variable -->
            <xsl:with-param name="list" select="$Variable_01"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="list2" select="$Variable_02"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="delimiter" select="','"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
        <xsl:text>]</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="tokenizeString">
        <!--passed template parameter -->
        <xsl:param name="list"/>
        <xsl:param name="list2"/>
        <xsl:param name="delimiter"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains($list, $delimiter)">
                <!-- get everything in front of the first delimiter -->
                <xsl:text>{"Group":"</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($list,$delimiter)"/>
                <xsl:text>", "Name":"</xsl:text>
                <xsl:call-template name="tokenizeAnother">
                    <xsl:with-param name="list2" select="$list2"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="delimiter" select="$delimiter"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
                <xsl:text>"},</xsl:text>
                <xsl:call-template name="tokenizeString">
                    <!-- store anything left in another variable -->
                    <xsl:with-param name="list" select="substring-after($list,$delimiter)"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="list2" select="substring-after($list2,$delimiter)"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="delimiter" select="$delimiter"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:text>{"Group":"</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="$list"/>
                <xsl:text>", "Name":"</xsl:text>
                <xsl:call-template name="tokenizeAnother">
                    <xsl:with-param name="list2" select="$list2"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="delimiter" select="$delimiter"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
                <xsl:text>"}</xsl:text>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="tokenizeAnother">
        <xsl:param name="list2"/>
        <xsl:param name="delimiter"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains($list2, $delimiter)">
                <!-- get everything in front of the first delimiter -->
                <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($list2,$delimiter)"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="$list2"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See it in action [here](http://xsltransform.hikmatu.com/pPqsHSZ).

Comment: It could indeed be simpler, as I hopefully show in my 2nd answer.

Answer (score 0):

For completion, here's a purely **XSLT 1.0** solution that does not require any extension functions:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:variable name="Variable_01">88888,777777</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="Variable_02">abc,xyz</xsl:variable>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:text>[</xsl:text>
    <xsl:call-template name="tokenize-to-pairs">
        <xsl:with-param name="left-text" select="$Variable_01"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="right-text" select="$Variable_02"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
    <xsl:text>]</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="tokenize-to-pairs">
    <xsl:param name="left-text"/>
    <xsl:param name="right-text"/>
    <xsl:param name="delimiter" select="','"/>
    <!-- output -->
    <xsl:text>{"Group":"</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(concat($left-text, $delimiter), $delimiter)" />
    <xsl:text>", "Name":"</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(concat($right-text, $delimiter), $delimiter)" />
    <xsl:text>"}</xsl:text>
    <!-- recursive call -->
    <xsl:if test="contains($left-text, $delimiter)">
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:call-template name="tokenize-to-pairs">
            <xsl:with-param name="left-text" select="substring-after($left-text, $delimiter)"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="right-text" select="substring-after($right-text, $delimiter)"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```